# Jmeter - JMS Publisher - How to get the value from XML request

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter, request

I'm trying to get a value from the xml-document which I send from JMS Publisher to JMS Subscriber.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sys1>
    <req>
        <id>123</id>
        <message>hello</message>
    </req>
</sys1>
```

The document gets transformed. I need to check if the "id"s in xml-document stay the same or not after transformation.
When I get "id" from the Subscriber - I just use Post Processor - XPath Extractor and get it.

But I get nothing when I use it in Publisher.

I read some jmeter mans and find that "This test element (XPath Extractor) allows the user to extract value(s) from structured **response** - XML or (X)HTML - using XPath query language."

Then I've tried to get it with the Regular Expression Extractor, but it only works with a response, too.
But how can I get it from the Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get access to the request data only using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), example code would be something like:

```
def id = new groovy.xml.XmlParser().parseText(ctx.getCurrentSampler().getTextMessage()).req.id.text()
```

if you want to store the result into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you can also do add the next line:

```
vars.put('id', id)
```

Once done you will be able to access the extracted value as `${id}` where required

in the above code `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for description of all methods and fields and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

You might also be interested in  [Apache Groovy - Processing XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html) chapter of Groovy documentation

Comment: Thanx! It helps.